# Modbus RTU Implementation in embedded C

Tags: c#, c, modbus, modbus-tcp

My question would be weird so I do apologize for that.

I am going to implement Modbus RTU Master in an electronic device Called "DiGi Module Connect Me 9210". From this device I will request some data from PIC, data like Nodes and Temperatures and Some other data. I just want to Implement FC 04/03/16 in my device.

The Digi Module is an electronic device so for this purpose I am going to create C# GUI to request data from the PIC Using GUI via DiGi Module because Digi will be connected with PIC using Modbus RTU Protocol. And after getting the data in Digi we will send that data on cloud using REST APIs.

From GUI to DIgI I will have TCP/IP and from DIGI to PIC I will have Modbus RTU and between Cloud and DiGi I will have REST APis.

I want to strip out my data in C# so I will just send request from the GUI to PIC via DIGI (so my DIGI would a bridge between GUI and PIC) to configure the node or get node data from PIC. I have to read almost 9999 registers in one go using 80 request or something else to get the data from 3X / 4X registers. Now the questions are.

☺ How to implement Modbus RTU in a device or a system.?

☺ How can I read all the 9999 registers via GUI because I might want to read all the RunTime data from the 3X registers.?

☺ How can I write/Read all the 4X registers in one shot as well.?

We are also implementing the paging technique so it means that page 0 will have 9999 registers and then page 1 will have 9999 registers. So if I want to read temperatures I have to go to page 0 and read the registers and if I want to read Speed values I have to go to page 1 and check all the registers.?

The GUI would look like some thing

User will add Node Number and then Temperature and Submit the request.

Comment: I've actually used a DiGi Connect Me to do some Modbus stuff a few years ago...  But some feedback on your question(s):  you are asking for a lot of different pieces of information.  It's better if you get more specific and break it down.

Comment: Thanks @Nanomurf for the reply. Let me break it down. -> How to implement Both Modbus RTU in Digi module? -> How to read 9999 registers using threads in c# gui in one shot? -> How can I control the threads..? –

Comment: @MuhammadAzeem There are way too many questions in here, and the scope of many of these questions are way to big - they're essentially asking people to either write your code or architect your whole system, and that's not suitable questions here. (It's also not clear what "strip my data " means). You should rather post several small, specific questions, one question per post.

Comment: @nos Thanks For the Comment. I think you are right I should go for one question per post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[libmodbus](http://libmodbus.org/) library could help you in that. I have implemented this library in digi module you only have to put your registers in loop and also copy the registers to convert it in rtu.